# How to solve broken dnf in Fedora 26 when I get "ImportError: bad magic number in 'six'"

Tags: linux, fedora, operating-systems

My dnf stop working and showing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 57, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    import dnf.base
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 37, in <module>
    import dnf.conf
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from dnf.conf.config import PRIO_DEFAULT, PRIO_MAINCONFIG, PRIO_AUTOMATICCONFIG
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/conf/config.py", line 26, in <module>
    from iniparse.compat import ParsingError, RawConfigParser as ConfigParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/iniparse/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .ini import INIConfig, change_comment_syntax
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/iniparse/ini.py", line 47, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: bad magic number in 'six': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
```

I really don't remmenber any thing that I installed besides Fedora's own updates via dnf distro-sync.
Could it be a problem with python version change?

I use Fedora 26 Workstation x86_64

Comment: You can start by verifying dnf: rpm -V dnf

Comment: Hi @HoD. rpm -V dnf returned nothing.

Comment: What happened immediately before this stopped working? Did you lose power in the middle of an upgrade, or something similar? When did it last work?

Comment: No. Nothing happened that I know of.

Comment: I ran yum-deprecated reinstall python3-six. Tried also reinstalling dnf abd python-dnf using yum-deprecated. Nothing, yet, solved it.

Comment: This is usually some bad copy installed by alternative python installers, for instance `pip`. I had to remove various bad copies including `rm /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py /usr/bin/six.pyc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the python `six` library is corrupt. What do you get with `rpm -V python3-six`? If this gives no output, the problem is elsewhere. However, if you get something like:

```
S.5....T.    /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/__pycache__/six.cpython-36.pyc
```

try removing the offending `pyc` file and try `sudo dnf list` again (`sudo rm /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/__pycache__/six.cpython-36.pyc`)

Note that it's not *generally* safe to just remove random files, but these `pyc` files are pre-compiled bytecode as an optimization, and will be recreated.

Note also that after recreation, `rpm -Vf` will *still* show the file as changed, because... it has. But it will probably fix this particular "bad magic number" problem.

If *that* doesn't work, something worse is going on.

Comment: rpm -V python3-six returned nothing too.

Comment: Well, that's odd. Can you try removing `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/__pycache__/six*.pyc`? Let's see what happens!

Comment: Nothing happened, also. :(

Comment: Okay, next thing. :) Do you have any _other_ python installed on the system?

Comment: Hi. This:
python                    python2.7-futurize        python35                  python3.5m                python3.6                 python3-coverage          
python2                   python2.7-pasteurize      python3.5                 python3.5m-config         python3.6m                python3-mako-render       
python2.7                 python3                   python3.5-config          python3.5m-x86_64-config  python3-chardetect        python3-pyinotify

Comment: Do you know where the python 3.5 stuff came from? How was it installed? Do you have any _other_ `six*.pyc` files somewhere under that?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I don't know where it came from. Probably dependencies ...

Comment: @tenshimsm But on Fedora 26, we only have `python2` (2.7) and `python3` (3.6). There's no 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking for any possibly conflicting files:

```
sudo find / -name 'six.py*'
```

If, for example, you have a file `/usr/bin/six.pyc`, python will try to use that first (due to module load order). Relocating/removing this file did the trick for me.

See also: [similar question on ask.fedoraproject.org](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/111697/how-to-solve-broken-dnf-in-fedora-26/?answer=111713#post-id-111713)